# Not getting desired results using the pivot operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a two column table but am not getting my desired results.

Here is a sample of the data in the Employees table:

```
DataPoint  Populated
name       Ram
email      ram@gmail.com
age        23
name       Shyam
email      shyam23@gmail.com
age        28
name       John
email      john@gmail.com
age        33
name       Bob
email      bob32@gmail.com
age        41
```

Here is what I want:

```
name   email                age
Ram    ram@gmail.com        23
Shyam  shyam23@gmail.com    28
John   john@gmail.com       33
Bob    bob32@gmail.com      41
```

Here is my code:

```
;WITH NeedToPivot AS(
 SELECT *
 FROM Employees)

 SELECT *
 FROM NeedToPivot
 PIVOT(MAX(Populated) FOR DataPoint IN("name","email","age"))x
```

Here is what it's returning:

```
name    email               age
Shyam   shyam23@gmail.com   28
```

Comment: Do you have something in your data to indicate which "group" a given row belongs to. Your code is working fine, it just isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Do you have an employee ID that would group email, name and age together?

Comment: Very helpful input as I'm new to using the pivot operator. It would make sense that the pivot operator needs to know how to group the data.

Comment: Yes typically you would use MAX(YourColumnThatIndicatesTheGroup).

Answer (score 2):

Based on feedback from Sean Lange I added an EmployeeId column to the Employees table. The pivot operator now understands my desired grouping and the query is returning exactly what I want.

Employees table now looks like this:

```
EmployeeId    DataPoint  Populated
1              name       Ram
1              email      ram@gmail.com
1              age        23
2              name       Shyam
2              email      shyam23@gmail.com
2              age        28
3              name       John
3              email      john@gmail.com
3              age        33
4              name       Bob
4              email      bob32@gmail.com
4              age        41
```